# Загрузка документа в формате docx сформированного из html

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Нужно организовать скачивание сформированного на странице html контента в формате docx на js.
Абстрактно это выглядит следующим образом:
у меня есть сформированная таблица на странице, при нажатии на кнопку скачать, html разметка страницы сохраняется в переменную преобразуется в документ docx и скачивается.
Кто знает, как это можно организовать? Какую библиотеку взять? Если будет небольшой пример, то бы ло бы супер!

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО подобные операции лучше проделывать на бэке. Типа, ты по методом POST закидываешь бэку html в виде строки, а он тебе возвращает данные, который ты и скачиваешь (создав ссылку на Blob и "кликнув" по ней). Получится что-то типа:

```
const { data } = response;
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
  officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });

const link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.click()
```

на чём построить бэк? Выбор либ большой. Например в npm один из вариантов поиска "html to docx" дал кучу предложений, среди них: [html-to-docx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-docx) (13 136 скачиваний за неделю)

Если бэк не вариант. то смотри либы типа [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js#html-docx-js). Они работают и на фронте и на бэке